# Google Cloud Storage: Download partial audio file

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I need to process large audio files in segments. Instead of downloading the full file and the extracting a timeframe, I'd like to only download the required segment (e.g. seconds 25 to 35).

As the API does not support this out of the box, what is the best way of only download segments of an audio file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from seconds its not supported, as Google Storage does not read the file and interpret it.

You can do segments of bytes. This is called reading ranges of bytes, which is supported in Cloud Storage.

You have to add a header `Range: bytes=20-2000` as documented [1].

In nodejs you would do something like this [2]

```
   const logFile = myBucket.file('access_log');
   logFile.createReadStream({
     start: 20,
     end: 2000
   })
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#range

[2] https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/607f6c1c8b9ae5414513957f54a5de2490c454b1/src/file.ts#L1178

Comment: I believe the map between seconds and byte range is specified in the metadata of the audio/video file. You would need to read that first and then do the range query. This is done out of the box with web media players.